# Any faster algorithm to transform from RGB to CMYK

Tags: java, image, transform, rgb, cmyk

This is how I am doing to convert from RGB to CMYK using the more "correct" way - i.e using an ICC color profile.

```
// Convert RGB to CMYK with level shift (minus 128)
private void RGB2CMYK(int[] rgb, float[][] C, float[][] M, float[][] Y, float[][] K, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) throws Exception {
    ColorSpace instance = new ICC_ColorSpace(ICC_Profile.getInstance(JPEGWriter.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToCMYKProfile)));
    float red, green, blue, cmyk[];
    //
    for(int i = 0, index = 0; i < imageHeight; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < imageWidth; j++, index++) {
            red = ((rgb[index] >> 16) & 0xff)/255.0f;
            green = ((rgb[index] >> 8) & 0xff)/255.0f;
            blue = (rgb[index] & 0xff)/255.0f;
            cmyk = instance.fromRGB(new float[] {red, green, blue});
            C[i][j] = cmyk[0]*255.0f - 128.0f;
            M[i][j] = cmyk[1]*255.0f - 128.0f;
            Y[i][j] = cmyk[2]*255.0f - 128.0f;
            K[i][j] = cmyk[3]*255.0f - 128.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is: it's prohibitively slow given a large image. In one case, it took about 104s instead of the usual 2s for me to write the data as a JPEG image. It turns out the above transform is the most time-consuming part.

I am wondering if there is any way to make it faster. **Note:** I am not going to use the cheap conversion algorithm one can find form the web.

**Update**: following haraldK's suggestion, here is the revised version:

```
private void RGB2CMYK(int[] rgb, float[][] C, float[][] M, float[][] Y, float[][] K, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) throws Exception {
    if(cmykColorSpace == null)
        cmykColorSpace = new ICC_ColorSpace(ICC_Profile.getInstance(JPEGWriter.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToCMYKProfile)));
    DataBuffer db = new DataBufferInt(rgb, rgb.length);
    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(db, imageWidth, imageHeight, imageWidth,  new int[] {0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff}, null);
    ColorSpace sRGB = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);

    ColorConvertOp cco = new ColorConvertOp(sRGB, cmykColorSpace, null);

    WritableRaster cmykRaster = cco.filter(raster, null);
    byte[] o = (byte[])cmykRaster.getDataElements(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, null);

    for(int i = 0, index = 0; i < imageHeight; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < imageWidth; j++) {
            C[i][j] = (o[index++]&0xff) - 128.0f;
            M[i][j] = (o[index++]&0xff) - 128.0f;
            Y[i][j] = (o[index++]&0xff) - 128.0f;
            K[i][j] = (o[index++]&0xff) - 128.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Update: I also found out it's much faster to do filter on a BufferedImage instead of a Raster. See this post: [ARGB int array to CMYKA byte array convertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069341/argb-int-array-to-cmyka-byte-array-convertion/24086306#24086306)

Comment: Tiny optimization, but your loops will go faster if you count from ```imageHeight - ``` to 0. ```i>= 0``` is a faster check than ```i < imageHeight```.

Comment: The way CMYK is structured isn't ideal for caching, but it's not horrible, either.

Comment: This parallelizes quite well with a fork-join pool.

Comment: Do you really need `float` precision here? Most CMYK based file formats uses 8 bit per channel, so it might be overkill...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use [`ColorConvertOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html). It uses optimized native code on most platforms, and supports ICC profile transforms.

Not sure how fast it will work when using `float` based `Raster`s, but it does the job.

Something like:

```
ICC_Profile cmyk = ...;
ICC_Profile sRGB = ...;

ColorConvertOp cco = new ColorConvertOp(sRGB, cmyk);

Raster rgbRaster = ...;
WritableRaster cmykRaster = cco.filter(rgbRaster, null); 

// Or alternatively, if you have a BufferedImage input
BufferedImage rgbImage = ...;
BufferedImage cmykImage = cco.filter(rgbImage, null);
```

Comment: Created Raster from my int array and applied ColorConvertOp. The encoding time dropped to less than 4s. The resulting image is a bit off color due to the fact I haven't embedded any ICC profile in the image. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool! 4s is still some time for a color conversion, but at least better than 104s... Conversion time will depend on profile complexity. And yes, you need to embed the same ICC profile you converted to, but that's trivial. The `ICC_Profile` has a `getData()` method, and you only need to dump that array to an `APP2/ICC_PROFILE` block (+ index/count and make sure you obey the JFIF segment size).

Comment: I'm done. Just need to write the index and total segments. I admit this makes the decoder happier. But I thought it could figure it out if it read all the APP2s. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should get rid of the memory allocation within the innermost loop. `new` is a prohibitively expensive operation. Also it might kick the garbage collector into action, which adds a further penality.

Comment: Unless escape analysis can put it in stack memory, but yes.

Comment: @dragon66 you just reuse the array.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: In my test, no improvement at all: 1s less which I won't consider an improvement. I think the biggest problem is the method call to fromRGB too many times

Comment: @dragon66 When you profile it, what percent of time goes to each?

Answer (score 1):

If you can affort the memory consumption, you could create a lookup table:

```
private void RGB2CMYK(int[] rgb, float[][] C, float[][] M, float[][] Y, float[][] K, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) throws Exception {
    ColorSpace cs = new ICC_ColorSpace(...);
    int[] lookup = createRGB2CMYKLookup(cs);
    for(int y = 0, index = 0; y < imageHeight; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++, index++) {
            int cmyk = lookup[rgb[index]];
            C[y][x] = ((cmyk >> 24) & 255) - 128F;
            M[y][x] = ((cmyk >> 16) & 255) - 128F;
            Y[y][x] = ((cmyk >>  8) & 255) - 128F;
            K[y][x] = ((cmyk      ) & 255) - 128F;
        }
    }
}

static int[] createRGB2CMYKLookup(ColorSpace cs) {
    int[] lookup = new int[16 << 20]; // eats 16m times 4 bytes = 64mb
    float[] frgb = new float[3];
    float fcmyk[];
    for (int rgb=0; rgb<lookup.length; ++rgb) {
        frgb[0] = ((rgb >> 16) & 255) / 255F;
        frgb[1] = ((rgb >>  8) & 255) / 255F;
        frgb[2] = ((rgb      ) & 255) / 255F;
        fcmyk = cs.fromRGB(frgb);
        int c = (int) (fcmyk[0] * 255F);
        int m = (int) (fcmyk[1] * 255F);
        int y = (int) (fcmyk[2] * 255F);
        int k = (int) (fcmyk[3] * 255F);
        int icmyk = (c << 24) | (m << 16) | (y << 8) | k; 
    }
    return lookup;
}
```

Now this may actually *worsen* performance for small images as it is. It will only help if you can re-use the lookup table for multiple images, but as your example looks you're using actually the same ICC profile over and over. Thus you could cache the lookup table and pay its initialization cost only once:

```
 static int[] lookup;
 static {
    ColorSpace cs = new ICC_ColorSpace(...);
    lookup = createRGB2CMYKLookup(cs);
 }

// convert always using (the same) lookup table
private void RGB2CMYK(int[] rgb, float[][] C, float[][] M, float[][] Y, float[][] K, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) throws Exception {
    for(int y = 0, index = 0; y < imageHeight; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++, index++) {
            int cmyk = lookup[rgb[index]];
            C[y][x] = ((cmyk >> 24) & 255) - 128F;
            M[y][x] = ((cmyk >> 16) & 255) - 128F;
            Y[y][x] = ((cmyk >>  8) & 255) - 128F;
            K[y][x] = ((cmyk      ) & 255) - 128F;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the memory concern, you are right if the images are all to be writen in CMYK color space. The truth is it could be for the most of time YCbCr